# Save altered images to camera roll in Swift 3

Tags: swift3, uiimage, ios10

The following function saves my background image into the camera roll. Ultimately, it is an image that my custom camera has just taken.

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(self.backgroundImage!, self, #selector(self.image(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)
```

But how do I save an image that has been altered? For example, I put a textfield on it. Which variable should I use instead of backgroundImage? Or should I use a different function like UIGraphicsImageRenderer?

Your help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get an image from current view you can use for example `CoreGraphics`. Below snippet assumes implementation in view controller and rendering it's whole view:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size)
if let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {

    self.view.layer.render(in: ctx!)
    let renderedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext() //remember to end context to not cause memory leak
}
```

where `renderedImage` is your image with text, provided that text field is in the view at the moment of rendering.

Comment: Wladek, thank you for your reply, I will try it! So, in order to save this renderedImage, do I have to create another function for UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum? Because if user wants to simply save backgroundImage, he can do so easily, but if he wants to save an altered image, I just create another function for saving it, right? Or my logic is incorrect?

Comment: You call 'UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum' with rendered image, your logic is correct if I understood well your comment.

Comment: Wladek, you just helped me to solve the problem I had for weeks. Thank you so much!